# Specify the encoding type in createAttachmentFromString() in C#

Tags: c#, encoding, base64, email-attachments

i have an image that is converted to a base64 string in the frontend and i have to attach it inside my email service as an attachment. i have read about this API CreateAttachmentFromString(String, String, Encoding, String) in Attachment Class. the first argument is the encoded string which would be my base64 string and third one is encoding.

What should be value for this encoding argument if its base 64 string. i have searched the System.Text.Encoding class but there is no reference to it.

I tried

```
string encodedAttachment = emailData.AttachmentData.Substring(emailData.AttachmentData.IndexOf(",") + 1);
byte[] data1 = Convert.FromBase64String(encodedAttachment);
string decodedString = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data1);
Attachment data = Attachment.CreateAttachmentFromString(decodedString, emailData.AttachmentName, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet);
email.Attachments.Add(data);
```

Still the attachment sent isnt right.

Comment: So you've got image data as `byte[]`... why are you then trying to interpret that as a UTF-8-encoded string? It's simply not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An image is not a string.
You cannot attach an image using `CreateAttachmentFromString()`.

Instead, use `new Attachment(new MemoryStream(bytes), ...)`.

Comment: "You cannot attach an image using CreateAttachmentFromString()."  why not?

Comment: @LastTribunal: Because images are not strings.